# Akka conversion to dalvik fails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, akka, dalvik

I want to use akka in my android app but during conversion I get following error:

```
Dx processing akka/kernel/Main$.class...
Dx processing akka/kernel/Main$$anon$1.class...
Dx 
trouble writing output: No expanded opcode for 01ffb17a AkkaException.scala:20@000b:     invoke-direct v0:NffffLakka/AkkaException$$anonfun$stackTraceToString$1;,      scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1.<init>:()V
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2
```

I am using akka 2.0.1 and adt 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.

Are there any ways to overcome this problem?

Comment: I've got no idea how that crosscompilation is done. But please try the latest master and see if the problem exists there as well.

Comment: I noticed that akka-kernel is slimmer now. I downloaded latest master today (3rd of June). akka-kernel is converted without any problems. I am using akka-remote as well and it is failing now on:           Dx processing akka/remote/netty/RemoteServerHandler.class...
Dx processing akka/remote/RemoteClientDisconnected$.class...
Dx 
trouble writing output: No expanded opcode for 0031d850 AkkaException.scala:21@0004: invoke-direct v0:N0000Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;, scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>:()V
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be hitting the limit of 64k method references in a dex file. There's not much you can do, other than reducing the size of the code that in that dex file. Either by removing code, or splitting some of the classes out into a separate dex file.